# How to save XML string in XML type column of a table in Postgresql using spring boot hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I want to the content of XML file in database. So, I am reading the file content into string and planning it to dump into XML data type column of table. I have following classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "testXml")
public class testXmlimplements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<testXml> {

@Column(name="xmlContent",nullable=false, columnDefinition = "xml")
    private String xmlContent;


public void setXmlContent( String  xmlContent)
{
    this.xmlContent = xmlContent;
}

public String  getXmlContent()
{
    return xmlContent;
}
```

But when I try to insert it, it gives me following error message:

> ERROR: column "xml_content" is of type xml but expression is of type
>   character varying   Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the
>   expression.

I am new to postgre and spring hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the XML type in case of Hibernate with pgsql database, you can check the [link](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Hibernate_XML_Type)  and it has been mentioned as.

Java class can be used to enable Hibernate to store and retrieve PostgreSQL "xml" typed fields as String objects. It's trivially adapted to parse the XML into a DOM and store from a DOM or whatever your preferred XML representation instead.

To tell Hibernate to use this UserType for a given mapped field, specify a Type annotation on the property, like:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="foo.bar.SQLXMLType")
private String markup;
```

Comment: can you provide the link?

Comment: Sorry, my bad .